# glob function in python with one wildcard

Tags: python, glob

I have a problem with the `glob.glob` function in Python.

This line works perfectly for me getting all text files with the name `002` in the two subsequent folders of Models:

```
     All_txt    = glob.glob("C:\Users\EDV\Desktop\Peter\Models\*\*\002.txt")
```

But going into one subfolder and asking the same:

```
     All_txt    = glob.glob('C:\Users\EDV\Desktop\Peter\Models\Texte\*\002.txt')
```

results in an empty list. Does anybody know what the problem here is (or knows another function which expresses the same)?

I double-checked the folder paths and that all folders contain these text-files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting an `r` in front of the string to make a raw string: `glob.glob(r'C:\Users\EDV\Desktop\Peter\Models\Texte\*\002.txt')`.  This will make it so the backslashes arent used for escaping the next character.

You could also do it without glob like so:

```
import os
all_txt = []
root = r'C:\Users\EDV\Desktop\Peter\Models\Texte'
for d in os.listdir(root):
    abs_d = os.path.join(root, d)
    if os.path.isdir(abs_d):
        txt = os.path.join(abs_d, '002.txt')
        if os.path.isfile(txt):
            all_txt.append(txt)
```

Comment: or use C like historical escaping with double-slashes 'c:\\Users\\EDV\\Desktop\\Peter\\Models\\Texte'